# Check SQLite database is already created

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am using Ionic / Cordova SQLite plugin and I want to be able to check if a database exists before calling a specific function. If I use `openDatabase("db", "", "name", dbSize, function() { };` it is called only when there is no database, however if I close the Android app and relaunch, the code inside `openDatabase()` doesnt get called at all.. should this be getting called if the db is already created? Is there another way to check the db is already created?

Basically, I need to call a function after I check there is a db.

```
db = openDatabase("dbn", "", "manager", dbSize, function() {

            console.log('is called'); // only shows when first creating db

            // USER table create
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                //tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE grips.db.user');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  user (id integer primary key,active_user, firstname, lastname, email, age, gym_id integer, set_time integer, date_created integer )');

                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  sets (id integer primary key,machine_name, device_id integer, weight_val integer, user integer,reps, exercise_id integer, workout_id, gym_id integer, calories,time_ago text, date_created integer)');

                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  devices (id integer primary key,mac_id text, device_type,gym_id integer,machine_id integer,machine_name,date_created integer)');

                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  workouts (id integer primary key,user integer,date_created integer)');

                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  pt_workouts (id integer primary key, img_url, name, video_url, admin_user integer, gym_id integer, gif_url, search_img, instructions, trainer_name, user_img, date_created integer)');



            }, function (error) {

            }, function () {

            });

        }, function (error) {

            console.log('open db second error');

        },function () {

            console.log('open db second');

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

openDatabase will either open an existing db or create a new one if it doesn't exist.

So if you do something like so:

```
    var db = null;
    db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "my.db", location: 'default'});
```

It will create the db if it's not there, or open the existing one. Then you can do the table interactions in a transaction like so:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS x (field1 text primary key, field2 text)");
    }, function (err) {
        alert("An error occurred while initializing the app");
    });
```

Or you can use the db object and check whatever else you need to check. I would also suggest that this is all done in a onDeviceReady() method (you may already be doing this)